# Copy column and paste formulas only - not values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy a column to the right of table and paste the formulas only (not values).

```
Sub acrescentaCols()
Dim oSheet As Worksheet

Set oSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
oSheet.Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

But this is copying also the values (because Excel considers values to be a formula too).

How do I fix this?

Comment: The `.Formula` property may start with or without `=`. The `values` you refer to are formulas without `=`.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. but how about the code? I can't remove the = wihout getting an error

Comment: use an if statement to see if the left first charactier of the formula is '=' then paste else ignore.  You will need to iterate.  But do not use the copy paste assign the formula instead it will be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments earlier:

```
Sub acrescentaCols()
Dim oSheet As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Set oSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
With oSheet
    Set rng = .Range(.Range("D1"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each cel In rng
        If Left(cel.Formula, 1) = "=" Then
            Range(cel.Offset(, 1), cel.Offset(, 1).End(xlToRight)).Formular1c1 = cel.Formular1c1
        End If
    Next cel
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It will not fit if there are empty cells in between while the header lines are not empty.

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying.  It goes to the bottom of the sheet and goes up to the first occupied cell then iterates through all from the first to the last occupied cell whether empty or not in column D.  I did have one error that your comment made me find.

Comment: I think it works. But, with a lot of iteration. I guess it is easier to define the range and check if each cell HasFormula

Comment: The only way to do this is through iteration, you could use find but you will need then to do a `do` loop jumping from one to the next, overall it is less iteration but you run the risk of having an "=" inside a string that will be picked up also. At least with my knowledge base this is the best way.

Comment: r1 (header): a | b | c | d | e r2 (data): =1 | 1 | 1 | (blank) | 1 will only be filled to column "c" even though by OP's code it would fill up to "e".

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, that I need to find the end of the column headers and stop.  The problem with that is you are assuming there are headers.  No where in the OP's example or explanation does he state that he has headers or that there is anything in the cells to the right of D.  I can see where he is just having the formulas put there all at once and will fill in the column data as he needs. If @NunoNogueira wants I can easily find the end of the headers in row 1 and set the extant of the right fill to that.

Answer (score 1):

The below should fix your immediate problem of only copying the formulas across and not the values, but I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. If you can give more information I'm sure I can help you acheive what you're trying to get to.

It seems as if you want to copy the formulae to every row to the right of column D to the very right edge of the worksheet?

It also seems like you want to copy the formulae only so they re-evaluate in their new location - or do you want to paste values only so that they hold the same values that they evaluated to in column D?

Anyway, give this a whirl.

```
Sub acrescentaCols()
Dim oSheet As Worksheet

Set oSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

For Each cell In oSheet.Range("D1", Range("D1").End(xlDown))
    If cell.HasFormula Then
        cell.Copy
        Range(cell, cell.End(xlToRight)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say paste the formula only - your method will paste the formula and then recalculate and your formula will show the result.  I think a better way to write that would be:

```
Sub acrescentaCols()

    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rCopied As Range

    Set oSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With oSheet
        .Columns("D:D").Copy

        Set rCopied = .Cells(1, 4).End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1).EntireColumn
        rCopied.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

    End With

End Sub
```

If you want to show the actual formula you could use a UDF something like:

```
Function GetFormula(Target As Range) As String
    If Target.HasFormula Then
        GetFormula = Target.Formula
    End If
End Function
```

If you want to apply this to a whole column you could use:

```
Sub acrescentaCols1()

    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rCopied As Range

    Set oSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With oSheet
        Set rCopied = .Cells(1, 4).End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1).EntireColumn
        rCopied.FormulaR1C1 = "=GETFORMULA(RC4)"
    End With

End Sub
```

This will probably kill your spreadsheet though - it will execute the UDF on all rows.

Comment: `For Each Cell in rCopied | Cell.FormulaR1C1 = GetFormulaR1C1(RC4) | Next Cell` and modify it to `GetFormulaR1C1 = Target.FormulaR1C1` plus set up an `InStr(Target.FormulaR1C1,"=")>0` criterion.

Comment: I'd use Target.HasFormula rather than look for an equals sign - `Hello, A = B` contains an equal sign but isn't a formula.

Comment: I need to copy-paste the formulas only. For example, in cell D5, I have the number 25, I don't want to copy paste it because it is a number

Comment: Copy-paste the formula as formula - so it recalculates and shows the result, or copy-paste the formula as text - so it displays the formula and not the result.  e.g. `=1+1`  do you want it to display `=1+1` **or** `2`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub acrescentaCols()
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng As Range

    Set oSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng1 = oSheet.Columns("D:D")
        Set rng1 = Intersect(rng1, rng1.Worksheet.UsedRange) 'for the used range only
    Set rng2 = Range(rng1, rng1.End(xlToRight))
    For i = 1 To rng1.Cells.Count 'for each row
        If Left(rng1(i, 1).Formula, 1) = "=" Then 'if it starts with an equal sign
            For j = 1 To rng2.Columns.Count 'then for each column in the copy
                rng2(i, j).FormulaR1C1 = rng1(i, 1).FormulaR1C1
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```