# How to copy formatting and formulas from an Excel range into another?

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop

My situation:

I have a piece of code that copies data from a database into Excel sheet, let's take this code

```
 RangeExcelData(objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("DATA").Range("D71"), rptLotNo)
```

To cut it short, RangeExcelData is a user-defined function in my VB.NET application that lets me copy the variable data into a range in Excel

I have lots of this in my code, having to copy an entire data from the database into a sheet.

I also have a formatted Excel worksheet where I put the data from the database. What I want to know is can I copy the format from the formatted Excel worksheet, into a space inside the worksheet?

Here is a little illustration of what I want, this is the formatted excel for example:

[image: This is the formatted Excel for example]

If the data exceeds the Excel, I want VB.NET to copy the format to the space next to it. Including the formulas that it may have:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your original values start at `B2` and end at `D7`, you can do something like this:

```
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")
With xlSheet
    .Range("B2:D7").Copy()
    .Range("E2:G7").PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats)
    .Range("E2:G7").PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats)

    ' Start adding the new values.
    .Range("E3:E6").Value = 4
    .Range("F3:F6").Value = 5
    .Range("G3:G6").Value = 6
End With
```

**Note:** Since you're copying the formulas as well *(not just the formats)*, any *fixed* values (if any) will be copied too, but that shouldn't matter since you'll be overwriting them with the new values.

**Result:**

[image: Result]

If you don't want the fixed values to be copied, you might check the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33568248/4934172). It's about VBA, but you can do the same thing in VB.NET.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly, If I copy the formulas, the respective reference will be copied too? I mean if per column there is a formula under each column, maybe line 3, then I could copy the formulas in line 3?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but if the formula in the first column is something like `=SUM(B3:B6)`, then the formula of the fourth column (first in second table) will be `=SUM(E3:E6)`. Unless, of course, you have something like `$B$3:$B$6` then the references will stay the same.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, thank you for your understanding and sorry if I confused you.

Comment: Not at all, glad I was able to help! Let me know if you still have any issues.

Comment: May I ask, can I control the value of range by variable? Say the range is `.Range("B2:D7").` but then I want to add 15 cells to it, move it via variable per se, do you have any idea how to do it programatically and not hard coded?

Comment: Are you trying to store the values of a range into one variable? If so, you're looking for a two-dimensional array. Example: `Dim arr As Object(,) = .Range("B2:D7").Value` and to print it back to a range: `.Range("B2:D7").Value = arr`.